# Initiate and Get backup file from one SQL server to another via database link

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, database-backups

From my development SQL Server, I want to initiate a backup on my production SQL Server that writes the backup to the development SQL Server disk via the database link.

For security reasons, I am unable to get drive permissions on the production SQL Server (which would allow me to initiate a restore on Dev from the Prod backup). This is a the only workaround I could come up with.

The overall goal is to get a full backup copy of Production every night and restore a copy to Development. This would give us a recent copy to work with in Dev.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't recognize the database.

```sql
--RUN FROM DEV Database

BACKUP DATABASE [PROD_DATABASE_LINK].[blog]
TO DISK = N'\\Dev_Database_Drive\D$\Backup\blog\blog_FullBackup_Test' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
     NAME = N'blog-Full Database Backup', 
     SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)

SET @SQL = 'BACKUP DATABASE [PROD_DATABASE_LINK].[dbo].[blog]TO  DISK = N''\\\Database_A_Drive\D$\Backup\blog\blog_FullBackup_Test'''
EXECUTE [DEV_DATABASE_LINK].dbo.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Eric

Comment: I don't understand: if it's on a different server, you need to execute it on that server, which you're not. Or you could used linked servers, but I don't see that either. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167603/copy-whole-database-from-sql-server-to-sql-server-using-linked-server

Comment: Charlieface, I am using linked servers. I just edited the original post to make it more obvious in the SQL that I was trying to make work.    As for using scripts to recreate the DB, the Prod database is 8 Gig. Not sure that is workable for such a large database

Comment: Doesn't look very "linked server"ish to me: you should have four part names, not three part `server.database.schema.procedure`

Comment: Charlieface- I am required to change some naming conventions if posting questions publicly by the customer. Some of our names are pretty specific and would identify my employer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand, but you can still obfuscate the names. So in your question you would put `BACKUP DATABASE [DEV_DATABASE_LINK].[someDB].[dbo].[blog] ...` with no necessity for `sp_executesql`. Or you can do `EXECUTE [DEV_DATABASE_LINK].[someDB].sys.sp_executesql @SQL`

Answer (score 0):

You can't backup a single table, and the UNC path should be `\\server\share\folder\file`.  So the BACKUP command should look something like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [blog] 
  TO DISK = N'\\DevServer\D$\Backup\VRVblog\VRVblog_FullBackup_Test.bak'
```

And to access the admin `D$` share the SQL Server service account would need to be an administrator on the target server.

BACKUP can't reference a database on a linked server, but you can send that batch to the target server to execute like

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    BACKUP DATABASE [blog] 
       TO DISK = N''\\DevServer\D$\Backup\VRVblog\VRVblog_FullBackup_Test.bak''
'

exec (@sql) at ProdServer
```

Comment: Blog is the database, not an individual table. I have updated the original post to clarify the SQl I was using has a databse link in the form of [Database_Link].[Databse to backup].

Comment: Thanks, But since I don't have permissions between the Dev and Production drives, the Prod backup file could not be written to the Dev drive. Its a catch 22 situation. That is why I thought that if I used Linked Servers, I could initiate a Prod backup from Dev that writes the backup file to dev.

Comment: Not being able to do something you’re not allowed to do is not a “catch 22”.  Acquiring a backup of a production database should require a high level of permission.

Comment: And the same people deigning me access are the same people making the request....   Short of making the Database Link work, I don't see a way around the file permission problem.

Comment: "I don't see a way around the file permission problem"  I don't understand.  Just grant the  production SQL Server service account permission to write the backup somewhere you can read from on the Dev server.

Comment: Once again, not my network. I am at the mercy of the admins. Come Monday morning meeting, however, I will be discussing it and referencing this thread.  Thank You !

Comment: Note you could also write the backup to Azure Blob Storage and read it back from there.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15  Then you would only need outbound HTTPS network access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, but you were correct,  you just can't get there from here because of permissions.

Since the question was posted, we had a contract/personnel change that has rectified the issue.